# JKWhy is my brisket rubbery when I cooked it

Tags: beef, smoking, brisket, smoke-flavor

Injected, cooked until 160, wrapped, cooked until 200, just like it says online. Still very rubbery and tough.

Maybe my meat thermometer is inaccurate? Maybe I should go beyond 200 next time.

It was a very small brisket, about 4.5 pounds.

[image: Smoker and meat temperature]

Comment: Hi Derek, and welcome to the site! I have a couple questions to help get you a good answer. Does your graph show time in hours? Did you insert your thermometer into the thickest part of the brisket?

Comment: Not sure. The thickest part of the brisket was pointy, thus exposing it to more surface area. I put it in a slightly thinner part but that was smack in the middle of the brisket. To actually work out which was more thermally central would require some integration.

I would like to add that even the part of the brisket containing the thermometer was rubbery as well—the whole thing was.

Comment: Brisket is so freaking difficult.  It is the triple Lindy of meat cooking.